# How to create Interactive/Classic Report with dynamic SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm running Apex 19.2 and I would like to create a classical or interactive report based on dynamic query.

The query I'm using is not known at design time. It depends on an page item value.

```
-- So I have a function that generates the SQL as follows
GetSQLQuery(:P1_MyItem);
```

This function may return something like

```
select Field1 from Table1
or
Select field1,field2 from Table1 inner join Table2 on ...
```

So it's not a sql query always with the same number of columns. It's completely variable.

I tried using **PL/SQL function Body returning SQL Query** but it seems like Apex needs to parse the query at design time.

Has anyone an idea how to solve that please ?

Cheers,
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: isn't there an option "Use Generic Column Names" ? I think if you enable that it doesn't try to get the column names on compile

Answer (score 1):

Enable the **Use Generic Column Names** option, as Koen said.

[image]

Then set **Generic Column Count** to the upper bound of the number of columns the query might return.

If you need dynamic column headers too, go to the region attributes and set **Type** (under Heading) to the appropriate value. PL/SQL Function Body is the most flexible and powerful option, but it's also the most work. Just make sure you return the correct number of headings as per the query.

Comment: Great..!! Is there any way if similarly we can use Interactive Grid instead of classic report and show dynamic SQL query in Oracle Apex 19.1. Really appreciated any help. :)

Comment: It looks like an Interactive Grid is more like an Interactive Report, where the region type's features depend on the metadata related to the query (data types mostly). So no, you can't do this the same way.